# Specify options with git commands via LibGit2Sharp

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

Is it possible to replicate git commands that use *options* using LibGit2Sharp?

For example I want to use commands like (but not limited to):

```
git fetch --all -p [fetch all remotes and prune any branches which don't exist]
git merge --ff-only origin/master [fast-forward merges only]
git merge IssueXyz master --no-commit --no-ff
```

Using merging as an example, in LibGit2Sharp the only method on Repository I can find for merging is:

```
public MergeResult Merge(Commit commit, Signature merger)
```

Which doesn't allow options to be specified.

But in the implementation of the method the merge is delegated to a Proxy:

```
GitMergeResultHandle mergeResultHandle = Proxy.git_merge(Handle, 
  new GitMergeHeadHandle[] { mergeHeadHandle }, 
  opts
```

where "opts" is a hard-coded instance of "GitMergeOpts" where "MergeFlags" looks like it could be used to specify the appropriate merge behaviour, if it weren't hard-coded:

```
internal struct GitMergeOpts
{
    public uint Version;

    public GitMergeFlags MergeFlags;
    public GitMergeTreeOpts MergeTreeOpts;
    public GitCheckoutOpts CheckoutOpts;
}
```

So what I am really trying to understand is how the library should be used to replicate more complex git commands that use options?

Or is this not the intended use-case for this library, in which case, any suggestions as to how else I can do this in C# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, optional arguments are given using `xxxOptions` objects, e.g. `Network.Fetch` accepts a `FetchOptions` object, in which you can specify arguments by setting the properties.

As libgit2sharp is still in active development, there are many featured to be developed. If you encounter a feature that is implemented in libgit2 but missing in libgit2, you can always create a pull request fixing it.

---

Regarding the specific case: `Merge` is a relatively new feature to libgit2sharp, and currently does not support the `--ff-only` behaviour. However, you could emulate the behaviour:

```
bool isFastForward = repo.Commits.FindCommonAncestor(repo.Head.Tip, commitToMerge)
    == repo.Head.Tip;
```

and then only merge if `isFastForward` is `true`.

Comment: I want to clarify one point - if `isFastForward` is true, then you want to do the fast-forward:  that is, you want to just check out the `commitToMerge` and not actually call merge.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. For now, I've switched to using NGit instead. This already supports many of the options through a fluent-syntax where each chained command (roughly) corresponds to parts of the equivalent git command.